# Why does array.map and [0,1,2].map in React work in different way?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am using **Framer motion** and would like my cards fetched from API to fade in nicely one by one. I am following this code [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/uotor?module=%2Fsrc%2FExample.tsx) from **Framer motion**.

This works completly fine:

```
<motion.ul className='container' variants={container} initial='hidden' animate='visible'>
    {[0, 1, 2].map((recipe) => (
        <motion.li key={recipe.idMeal} variants={item}>
            <RecipeCard />
        </motion.li>
    ))}
</motion.ul>
```

And this one (just changed `[0,1,3]` to `recipes`) just treats all the cards as one object and they all animate at the same time:

```
<motion.ul className='container' variants={container} initial='hidden' animate='visible'>
    {recipes.map((recipe) => (
        <motion.li key={recipe.idMeal} variants={item}>
            <RecipeCard />
        </motion.li>
    ))}
</motion.ul>
```

Here is how `recipes` look:

[image: recipes]

How do I fix it so that cards stagger and animate one by one and not as one object?

EDIT - Full code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import RecipeCard from "./RecipeCard";
import "./App.css";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

function App() {
const request = `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=chicken`;
const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
}, []);

const getRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(request);
    const data = await response.json();
    setRecipes(data.meals);
    console.log(data.meals);
};

const container = {
    hidden: { opacity: 1, scale: 0 },
    visible: {
        opacity: 1,
        scale: 1,
        transition: {
            when: "beforeChildren",
            staggerChildren: 0.1,
        },
    },
};

const item = {
    hidden: { y: 20, opacity: 0 },
    visible: {
        y: 0,
        opacity: 1,
    },
};

return (
    <div className='App'>
        {/* <form>
            <input type='text' />
            <button type='submit'>Search</button>
        </form> */}
        <motion.ul className='container' variants={container} initial='hidden' animate='visible'>
            {recipes.map((recipe) => (
                <motion.li key={recipe.idMeal} variants={item}>
                    <RecipeCard />
                </motion.li>
            ))}
        </motion.ul>
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox example for your problem? One that is using the recipe data.

Comment: I just changed the inline array for an object in the codesanbox you provided and it is working fine

Comment: In the code you posted you are missing the `className="item"` in your `motion.li` tag

Comment: In the first example, all your react keys end up being `undefined` since the numbers won't have an `idMeal` property, you should be seeing a react warning about duplicate, or non-unique, keys. In the second the keys at least have a chance at being unique. As @David says, if you can provide a ***working*** codesandbox with the `recipes` data we can probably see what's going on better. Also, what is the value of `item` for the `variants` prop?

Comment: I have edited the post and added full code. It is not about missing `className` or missing `key`. The code seems to be working fine for a predefined array. My array is getting fetched from an API and it doesn't work as intended.