# [0,1,2,3].map works fine, array.map gives strange results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I am using framer motion and I am trying to achieve stagger so that every next child has some nice delay. There is one crucial line of code in which when I replace `[0, 1, 2, 3].map` with `recipes.map` suddenly all of the children are treated as one huge block and they do not stagger.

Just check out this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-violet-349qk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) and you will surely know what I mean. What is wrong with this code? I am losing my mind :)

```
function App() {
  const request = `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=chicken`;
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
  }, []);

  const getRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(request);
    const data = await response.json();
    setRecipes(data.meals);
    console.log(data.meals);
  };

  const container = {
    hidden: { opacity: 1, scale: 0 },
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      scale: 1,
      transition: {
        when: "beforeChildren",
        staggerChildren: 0.5
      }
    }
  };

  const item = {
    hidden: { x: 100, opacity: 0 },
    visible: {
      x: 0,
      opacity: 1
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <motion.ul variants={container} initial="hidden" animate="visible">
        {[0, 1, 2, 3].map(recipe => (
          <motion.li key={recipe.idMeal} variants={item}>
            <RecipeCard title={recipe.strMeal} />
          </motion.li>
        ))}
      </motion.ul>
      <motion.ul variants={container} initial="hidden" animate="visible">
        {recipes.map(recipe => (
          <motion.li key={recipe.idMeal} variants={item}>
            <RecipeCard title={recipe.strMeal} />
          </motion.li>
        ))}
      </motion.ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does array.map and \[0,1,2\].map in React work in different way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602351/why-does-array-map-and-0-1-2-map-in-react-work-in-different-way)

Comment: No, it is my post. I have rewritten it to make question simpler.

Comment: "Just check out this demo and you will surely know what I mean" ... I really don't.  What am I looking at, and what specifically is the problem (besides a lot of broken images)?  It's not clear what you mean by "one huge block and they do not stagger" ... what's a block, and what doesn't stagger?

Comment: There's no `recipe.idMeal` defined in your original code. Which means your original code has an error which you might not aware. You could define recipes as constant somewhere to first explore the problem before wire it with `setState`, this will help solve the problem faster.

Comment: @ablaszkiewicz1 Next time, please just [edit] your original post if you want to clarify the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a bit tricky, but you need to animate only when the items are available:

```
animate={recipes.length > 0 && "visible"}
```

That's because on the first render you actually animate an empty array.

```
animate="visible"
```

Then, when you update the `recipes` after the async call, you don't trigger the animation again.

```
const container = {
  hidden: { opacity: 1, scale: 0 },
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    scale: 1,
    transition: {
      staggerChildren: 0.5
    }
  }
};

const item = {
  hidden: { x: 100, opacity: 0 },
  visible: {
    x: 0,
    opacity: 1
  }
};

const request = `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=chicken`;

function App() {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getRecipes = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(request);
      const data = await response.json();
      setRecipes(data.meals);
      console.log(data.meals);
    };
    getRecipes();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <motion.ul
        variants={container}
        initial="hidden"
        animate={recipes.length > 0 && "visible"}
      >
        {recipes.map(recipe => (
          <motion.li key={recipe.idMeal} variants={item}>
            <RecipeCard title={recipe.strMeal} />
          </motion.li>
        ))}
      </motion.ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit eager-mestorf-i8y14]

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please also explain me why first child animates also on Y? First child does this slide from bottom.

Comment: That's because the first item centered and then all items appeared and it showed on top. Please try to just add a new question instead of asking in comments.